# How to get back name of the number from Max function?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

So I have this question, using a toy example:

```
a={1,"this"};
b={2,"that"};

result=Max[0,a[[1]],b[[1]]]
```

the result will be 2. However what I want to obtain is "that" (or at least "b"). How do I do this without making dozens of "If"s and conditionals??

Comment: `a = {1, "this"};
b = {2, "that"};
#[[Ordering[#, -1, #[[1]] &]]] &@{a, b}`?

Comment: Shorter `a = {1, "this"}; b = {2, "that"}; #[[Ordering[#, -1]]] &@{a, b}`

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate.  I feel that the subject is already well covered there.  (And several other places.)  Please review the answers there; if afterward you disagree vote or flag to reopen.

Comment: Mods should have a way to vote normally

Comment: @belisarius If you disagree with the closure please vote to reopen.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nah, I posted my answer as a comment because I thought the question was surely covered somewhere else. The comment was just a rant.

Comment: @belisarius Okay. I agree that it would be good to be able to cast a normal vote but I suppose that could be seen as indecisiveness.

Comment: Please don't use the same post to ask more questions. Use a new post instead.

Comment: ok, do I do it now, or just leave it like this (and take the advice for the future)?

Comment: Please do it now. I voted to keep this closed to encourage you to remove your edit and post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

If you have *Mathematica* on the Raspberry Pi (or *Mathematica* 10), you could use [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) to store your data, which allows you to do these operations easily:

```
With[{a = <|1 -> "this", 2 -> "that"|>},
    a@Max@Keys@a
]
(* that *)
```

You can convert your list to an association as: `Association @@ Rule @@@ {a, b}`

Comment: Show a screen capture, or it didn't happen

Comment: @belisarius [Now vote!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/byqosm.png) :D

Comment: Ok, Ok, you have it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a={1,"this"};
b={2,"that"};

Max[0, a[[1]], b[[1]]] /. Rule @@@ {a, b}
```

This gives :

> that

Comment: wooooooow, thank you!

Comment: can I ask one more thing? how do I get whole b back? I'm just mesmerized by 3 @@@ and how it works:)

Comment: To obtain {2,"that"} instead of "that", you can do `Max[0, a[[1]], b[[1]]] /. ((#[[1]] -> #) & /@ {a, b})`

Answer (score 0):

```
a={1,"this"};
b={2,"that"};

Cases[{a, b}, {key_, value_} /; (key == Max[{a, b}[[All, 1]]])]
```

or

```
Select[{a, b}, (#[[1]] == Max[{a, b}[[All, 1]]] &)]
```

For variety's sake.  Likely not the way to go for long lists though.